# retrieving specific object from array and printing value from it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I am trying to look through an array for an object with the value `'Title' = 'Title'`. Then I want to print a second value on that object, in this case the value sitting at the key `Value`.

When I use the following method of filtering:

```
{{logEntry.StringValues | filter:{'Title':'Title'}:true}}
```

This prints the following:

```
[ { "GenericID" : null,
    "PropertyInfoName" : "Title",
    "Title" : "Title",
    "Value" : "Test Date Formatter",
    "class" : "string-editor-field",
    "data-val" : "true",
    "data-val-required" : "The Title field is required.",
    "id" : "Title",
    "name" : "Title",
    "type" : "text"
} ]
```

Instead of the entire object, I want to print the value sitting in `Value`.

This obviously works with the `ng-repeat` directive as such:

```
<h1 ng-repeat="field in logEntry.StringValues | filter:{'Title':'Title'}:true">
{{field.Value}}
</h1>
```

But I would like not to use the `ng-repeat` directive and directly print the value. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would appreciate if the people downvoting could give me some feedback on what in the format of my question is the cause of the downvoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/jocoqu/3/edit

```
  $scope.selectedTitle = $filter('filter')($scope.logEntry,{'Title':'Title'},true)[0].Value;
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware that this solution that I included in the question works. But as I also said in my question I would very much like to not use the ng-repeat directive for this solution as I feel it is a "dirty" solution.